# What CSS element would show a hidden div as a blank space?

Tags: wordpress

On my Wordpress site, the Leaflet Maps Marker plugin displays a map of locations. In the source code, each map location flag is defined inside a DIV tag, e.g.

```
<div id="lmm_geo_tags_4c74453a_14" class="lmm-geo-tags geo">Brewery Lane: <span class="latitude">53.346031</span>, <span class="longitude">-6.263213</span></div>
```

The DIV tags are visible in the page source but appear as blank lines on the page, creating a massive white space underneath the map: http://www.glutenfreeireland.com/test-map/

The plugin author hasn't been able to find the solution (http://wordpress.org/support/topic/space-or-gap-between-map-and-marker-list) and the theme developers responded to support emails saying it's not caused by the theme.

Are there CSS elements which would show DIV tags as blank spaces or other elements they would conflict with? The map page is the only page this issue occurs on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look more into it, you wrapped it in a

```
<pre>
```

tag which is causing this.

If I change your tag to a div, everything is fine.

Comment: Nice catch on the `<pre>` I totally didn't see that when I was looking at the source in the URL provided.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's brilliant. I'm now working between the plugin developer and the theme designer to identify the source of the <pre> tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble with the hidden `<div>` elements still generating space underneath the map, you could always try adjusting the height of the map container.

```
<div id="lmm_ec964ab4" style="height: 625px" class="mapsmarker layermap layer-1">
  ...
  <div id="lmm_geo_tags_ec964ab4_1" class="lmm-geo-tags geo">
  ...
</div>
```

By adding the **height**-style to the `<div>` with the `.mapsmarker` class, you can control the height of the content and its box, such that the overflow of the `.lmm-geo-tags` elements are hidden.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I've gone with the <pre> tag answer but your answer was also useful for my own knowledge.

Comment: Any time, the `<pre>` tag answer is the right one to go with!